# ASP.Net Control.OnInt and HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I'm digging around with HttpContext and the OnInit event for a custom control, after realizing that a few checks are not responding in the desired manner.

Within the current context's items collection, I store an object (serialized) that I would like to interrogate once on every post back. The first time the control is rendered, will the items[] be null, it then gets populated somewhere down the line and the user clicks a button to post back data.

Now, within the button submit event, I set the items[key] to null to ensure that on the post back I don't have anything stored, but it always contains a value.

I'm assuming that the OnInit handler has a reference to the previous state, thus 'falsely' assuming that the items[] should contain a value. Is this something to do with the way OnInit works, or am I missing the bigger picture?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Items` is not persisted across requests. From the initial request to the postback request, that represents two distinct request lifecycles between the client and server, and two separate instances of `Items`. Persisting data across requests requires using Session, Cache, or ViewState.

Comment: but that does not make sense. the items[] is persisted between the two different requests, for example: items[key] = object when user logs in, user continues through application and decides to submit changes to profile. during submit, changes should be stored, and items[key] = null. but on post back, items[key] = object and not null, meaning, the items[] gets persisted?

Comment: i would've preferred a cache object myself, have to fix 3rd party code :'(.